# Adding character count on RichTextInput for React-Admin

Tags: reactjs, react-admin, tiptap

I was trying to have a character count in the RichTextInput for React-Admin using the tiptap's extension-character-count package, but can't managed to get the count when typing in the RichTextInput. Any advice in this?

Below the code:

```
import {
  RichTextInput,
  DefaultEditorOptions,
  useTiptapEditor,
} from 'ra-input-rich-text';
import CharacterCount from '@tiptap/extension-character-count';
import { ToggleButton } from '@mui/material';

export default function RichEditor(props) {
  const { limit, ...rest } = props;
  const editorOptions = {
    ...DefaultEditorOptions,
    extensions: [
      ...DefaultEditorOptions.extensions,
      CharacterCount.configure({
        mode: 'nodeSize',
        limit,
      }),
    ],
  };
  const testEditor = useTiptapEditor();

  return (
    <RichTextInput
      editorOptions={editorOptions}
      helperText={(
        <span className="character-count">
          {testEditor?.storage?.characterCount?.characters()}
          /
          {limit}
          &nbsp;characters
          <br />
          {testEditor?.storage?.characterCount?.words()}
          words
        </span>
      )}
      {...rest}
    />
  );
}
```